# How can I convert a font from Font Book to .ttf?

Tags: macos, font-book

I am programming an application for IOS 5, but I need to use a different font. I found the perfect font for the job in Font Book, but it needs to be a TrueType Font file. Is there an easy way to do this?

By the way, if you can tell me how to make my own, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Font Book is an application, not a font format. Some fonts that appear in Font Book *are* True Type fonts. For those that are not, the question is about converting that specific format.

To find the file for a particular font, select it in Font Book, control-click it, and select "Show in Finder". You can then see what the format is on the file.